# Run user's systemd timer while they don't have any open session

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

Are [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) per user [systemd-timer](/questions/tagged/systemd-timer) running for offline users ? If not, is it possible to allow them to be running for users within a specific group ? Will the target service of the timer be launched correctly as the user it is supposed to run for this way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search for [systemd users] found [this answer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances) as the first result for you:

> The systemd user instance is started after the first login of a user
>   and killed after the last session of the user is closed. Sometimes it
>   may be useful to start it right after boot, and keep the systemd user
>   instance running after the last session closes, for instance to have
>   some user process running without any open session. Lingering is used
>   to that effect. Use the following command to enable lingering for
>   specific user:
>
> ```
> # loginctl enable-linger username
> ```

Enable this as a group level does not appear to be supported. Instead, enable it for every member of the group.

Comment: @Mark can you tell how lingering can be applied without a reboot? I made [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462845/45546) for this, but I guess it could also just be an extension of this answer.

Comment: @Zulan You don't have to reboot, but I don't see any way around the need for the user in question to log out and back in again. .