# How to apply lingering immedeately

Tags: systemd

As per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292938/45546), I enabled lingering for a user on a headless system. However in `loginctl list-sessions`, the user is not listed yet. If I login with this user by ssh it is shown, once I disconnect again it is missing.

How can I generate the lingering session without restarting the entire system

I have unsuccessfully tried to `systemctl restart systemd-logind`.

Edit: My goal is to run a timer controlled by this user. If i try this form a `sudo -iu` shell after enabling lingering, I get the following error:

```
$ systemctl --user status servicename
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

If I login per ssh (and a session shows up in loginctl) it works as epxected. But now I noticed it only works within the ssh shell, still not in the `sudo` shell. So it is in fact probably not related to the session.

Comment: You might want to explain *why* you want to enable linger. Do you want to run user units at boot, such as services or timers? If so, that should work, regardless of sessions... See my answer below. Edit your question if you'd like to explain why you think you need lingering and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger thanks for your clarification. My apologies for not including enough information leading to an XY-Problem. I have edited the question to include more information what I try to do and why I though it was wrong. I guess my actual question sohuld have been *How to run `systemctl` in a `sudo` shell*. I will gladly accept your answer - which helped me out of the dead end - and possibly post another question if I cannot resolve the other issue.

Comment: I edited my answer to cover your follow up. In short, you need to export `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID` when you're using `sudo` to become the new user. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're confusing "users" with "sessions" here.

Using `loginctl enable-linger myuser` will make the user manager for user `myuser` start at boot (and start immediately if it's not yet started), but it won't really start any sessions for the user (those only happen when the user logs in.)

If you use the `loginctl list-users` command you'll see the effects of it. You can also use `ps -fu myuser` to see the user manager (`systemd --user`) running for your user as soon as you enable linger:

```
[root@myhost ~]# loginctl list-users
UID USER
  0 root

1 users listed.
[root@myhost ~]# ps -fu myuser
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
[root@myhost ~]# loginctl enable-linger myuser
[root@myhost ~]# ps -fu myuser
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
myuser   12345     1 20 18:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
myuser   12349 12345  0 18:44 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
[root@myhost ~]# loginctl list-users
 UID USER      
   0 root      
1001 myuser

2 users listed.
```

But no new sessions for `myuser` exist, since it's not logged in through the console, GUI or SSH:

```
[root@myhost ~]# loginctl list-sessions
SESSION UID USER SEAT TTY  
      1   0 root      tty0

1 sessions listed.
```

But regardless of sessions, the user manager is started, so if your user has user units (such as services or timers), those will get started at boot regardless of the user having logged in or created a session yet.

I hope that explains it to you.

---

**UPDATE**: From your edit to the question, looks like the trouble you're really having is running `systemctl --user` commands from a `sudo -i` shell and not an SSH session.

You can work around that by exporting the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` after you switch to the user, such as:

```
$ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID
```

Or:

```
$ XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID systemctl --user status servicename
```

The reason you don't need that while logging in through SSH is that SSH will authenticate you with PAM and one of the PAM modules will set those environment variables for you. If you use `sudo`, you don't go through PAM (at least not the full PAM stack) so you don't get these properly set.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for two answers in one! Not only does your instruction help me with the task, you also clearly explain *why* it is necessary. Solved both my X and Y problem.

Comment: anyone aware of any security impact in setting this variable? I mean, any user obviously could set it for themselves but maybe it makes sense to lock it down somehow.